# Aspas simples são permitidas em JSON?

Tags: json

Posso representar um objeto JSON dessa maneira?

```
{
    'helloWorld': true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [especificação do formato JSON](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) diz claramente que somente aspas duplas podem ser usadas, mais específicamente `U+0022`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Não, apenas aspas duplas são permitidas em JSON. O exemplo da pergunta gera um objeto inválido, conforme pode ser testado no link: http://jsonlint.com/

O certo seria:

```
{
    "helloWorld": true
}
```

Note que é exigido que o nome da propriedade esteja entre aspas duplas, portanto, a seguinte notação também é inválida:

```
{
    helloWorld: true
}
```